# How do I draw lines using LineRenderer on a canvas in 2D Unity, so that the lines don't go diagonally to point A

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, math, graphics, 2d

I'm trying to build a logic gate simulator, however, I've noticed that the line drawing system I'm using looks messy and unorganized for drawing wires in between two gates...

I'm trying to avoid the fact it goes diagonally from point A to point B, however, I'm not sure how to do it, or what the type of line drawing that is called:
[This is what I'm trying to avoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzK8G.png)

Rather, I want a system that does a sharp corner like this, and makes it look more organized:
[This is what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GTxW.png)

This is another picture of what I'm trying to achieve:
[A logic gate drawer, something I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpluX.png)

This is the code I use for drawing the lines in between 2 selected objects:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LineDrawer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform startPoint;
    public Transform endPoint;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(startPoint != null && endPoint != null)
            RefreshLine();
    }

    private void RefreshLine()
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, startPoint.position);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, endPoint.position);
    }
}
```

It's very simple, and does what it needs to, but I need a way for it to automatically cut the wiring up so it goes cleanly...

Comment: draw multiple lines

Comment: Is there maybe an equation I can use to do this more efficiently? Or maybe a tutorial? I would find a tutorial, but I'm not even sure how to word this problem exactly, and how to look for it...

Comment: Add 2 points in the middle with the x set somewhere between the 2 existing points x's,  set the y's to the start and end point y's values respectively.

Comment: The thing is you are asking how to draw the lines (as mentioned by @hijinxbassist above simply add more points that only go in rectangular movements)  ... however I think what you are actually asking/looking for is an algorithm to layout the given items and connections in the first place - which is fairly too broad here